# How to display table in parent child hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, parent-child

I have array look like this.

```
var recursiveArray = [
    {
        "ProductCode": "50007",
        "SerialNumber": 288890,
        "SubAssemblyNumber": 288891,
        "Children": [
            {
            "ProductCode": "50007",
            "SerialNumber": 288891,
            "SubAssemblyNumber": 288892,
            "Children": [
                {
                    "ProductCode": "51660",
                    "SerialNumber": 288892,
                    "SubAssemblyNumber": 288894
                }
            ]
            }, {
                "ProductCode": "51660",
                "SerialNumber": 288891,
                "SubAssemblyNumber": 288893
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "ProductCode": "51660",
        "SerialNumber": 288890,
        "SubAssemblyNumber": 288895,
        "Children": [{
            "ProductCode": "50007",
            "SerialNumber": 288895,
            "SubAssemblyNumber": 288896
        }]
    }
];
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patel33hardik/6ps8n3rL/4/)

What I have done is in this fiddle to display table but I could not find how to give indentation at a deep level.

I want output as following:

[image: Output]

Comment: For this hierarchy ul->li would be better used than table since indentation is automatically applied.

Comment: definitely, it would be better in ul-li but, need to more time on styling and hard to align other detail with the same level. i.e product_code, stock and destroy.

Comment: If you use rowspan 6 in picture right col has 6 rows you could be able have ul li in a single column on the left and set line height to match right side. Otherwise your approach could also work, good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a single recursive function which keeps track of the current indent level as a parameter. When it needs to be called recursively, concatenate `'&emsp;'` to the parameter:

```
function append(parent, indent = '') {
  for (const item of parent) {
    createElement(item, indent);
    if (item.Children) {
      append(item.Children, indent + '&emsp;');
    }
  }
}
append(recursiveArray); // initial call
```

Live snippet:

```js
var recursiveArray = [{
  "ProductCode": "50007",
  "SerialNumber": 288890,
  "SubAssemblyNumber": 288891,
  "Children": [{
    "ProductCode": "50007",
    "SerialNumber": 288891,
    "SubAssemblyNumber": 288892,
    "Children": [{
      "ProductCode": "51660",
      "SerialNumber": 288892,
      "SubAssemblyNumber": 288894
    }]
  }, {
    "ProductCode": "51660",
    "SerialNumber": 288891,
    "SubAssemblyNumber": 288893
  }]
}, {
  "ProductCode": "51660",
  "SerialNumber": 288890,
  "SubAssemblyNumber": 288895,
  "Children": [{
    "ProductCode": "50007",
    "SerialNumber": 288895,
    "SubAssemblyNumber": 288896
  }]
}];


if (recursiveArray.length > 0) {
  $('#AttachedSubAssembly').append(`
                <tr>
                    <th width="60%">Subassy S/N</th>
                    <th width="20%">Product code</th>
                    <th width="10%">Stock</th>
                    <th width="10%">Destroy</th>
                </tr>
            `);
}
function append(parent, indent = '') {
  for (const item of parent) {
    createElement(item, indent);
    if (item.Children) {
      append(item.Children, indent + '&emsp;');
    }
  }
}

function createElement(item, indent) {
  $('#AttachedSubAssembly').append(`
<tr id="Row${item.SubAssemblyNumber}">
<td> ${indent} <a class="btn-green bg-transparent" href="serial_number.html?serial_number=${item.SubAssemblyNumber}">
${item.SubAssemblyNumber}</a></td>
<td>${item.ProductCode}</td>
<td>
<div class="col-md-1">
<div class="radio radio-success">
<input type="radio" name="Options${item.SubAssemblyNumber}" id="Stock${item.SubAssemblyNumber}" value="Stock">
<label for="Stock${item.SubAssemblyNumber}" class="main-label"></label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="col-md-1">
<div class="radio radio-success">
<input type="radio" name="Options${item.SubAssemblyNumber}" id="Destroy${item.SubAssemblyNumber}" value="Destroy" checked="checked">
<label for="Destroy${item.SubAssemblyNumber}" class="main-label"></label>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
`);
}
append(recursiveArray);
```

```css
table tr td {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="AttachedSubAssembly" class="table">
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, @CertainPerformance for quickly resolving my problem.
Exactly what I want. I was stuck into a recursive function and not sure how to track the level of depth.

Thanks again